# Why WebSocket example has a static method?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am learning .net core and exploring WebSockets. I found many examples out there and the majority are variations of the official [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Here is the [Sample App](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/websockets/samples/7.x/WebSocketsSample/Controllers/WebSocketController.cs).

My question is what is the reason the `Echo` method in the controller is made static? I am injecting services into the controller class and am unable to use their methods in the static context. Is it ok to make that instance method?

```
public class WebSocketController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/ws")]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await Echo(webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private static async Task Echo(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
            new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

        while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            await webSocket.SendAsync(
                new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
                receiveResult.MessageType,
                receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
                CancellationToken.None);

            receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
                new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        }

        await webSocket.CloseAsync(
            receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
            receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
            CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```